# Collapse feature using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have html like below i want collapse feature if clicked on h2 then relevant subfolder should be open and if other subfolder is open then it should closed automatically.

```
<div class="RootFolder">
  <h2>One</h2>
  <div class="Subfolder">a</div>
</div>

<div class="RootFolder">
  <h2>two</h2>
  <div class="Subfolder">b</div>
</div>

<div class="RootFolder">
  <h2>three</h2>
  <div class="Subfolder">c</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.Subfolder{
 display:none;
}
```

I don't know how to achieve this thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
$("h2").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".Subfolder").show();
});
```

If you want to toggle, use this:

```
$("h2").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".Subfolder").toggle();
});
```

By load, if you want all the `.Subfolder`s to be hidden, use this:

```
$(".Subfolder").hide();
```

And you need to give all these inside `$(document).ready();` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Subfolder").hide();
    $("h2").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".Subfolder").toggle();
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kBk2D/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$(".Subfolder").hide(); //intially hiding all the `subfolder`
$("h2").click(function(){
   $(this).next('subfolder').show(); //showing only the div after h2
});
```